# Match existing characters together into words and check if the words appear in the given word list?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, concatenation

I have a list of words like this:

```
string[] listWords = "la,lam,lan,son,som,some,mos,mao,sehi,noesrh,nroeh,doise".Split(',');
```

**The above list words is a combination of characters and they all have meanings.** We can temporarily call it a dictionary.

**Next, I have a multiple lists of character arrays like this:**

```
string[] charArr1 = "a,j,s".Split(',');
string[] charArr2 = "c,l,o".Split(',');
string[] charArr3 = "d,m,n".Split(',');
string[] charArr4 = "n,e,w".Split(',');
string[] charArr5 = "f,o,x".Split(',');
string[] charArr6 = "h,q,z".Split(',');
string[] charArr7 = "i,r".Split(',');
```

**I want to concatenate characters together. For each charArray I will take 1 character out and concatenate them together to become words, then I will check if these concatenated words are in the listwords[] list or not. If it is present, I will save the word in the saveWords[] array.**
Condition:

- Characters of the same charArray[] are not concatenated together and each charArray[] can only select one single character each time.
- Match all cases and not miss any cases.

**Eg:**

- a+c -> ac (Match correctly) -> search in listwords[] -> does not appear
- a+j (Improper matching)
- a+s (Improper matching)
- a+c+d -> acd (Match properly) -> search in listwords[] -> does not appear
- s+e+i+h -> seih (Match correctly) -> search in listwords[] -> does not appear
- s+e+h+i -> sehi (Match correctly) -> search in listwords[] -> if this word appears-> save to saveWords[] array

***What I mean is that the concatenation of characters will not miss any cases. Eg:***

> - charArr1[]+charArr2[] -> will match the following cases: a+c, a+l, a+o, j+c, j+l, j+o, s+c, s+l, s+o
> - charArr2[]+charArr1[] -> will match the following cases: c+a, c+j, c+s, l+a,l+j, l+s,o+a,o+j, o+s
> - charArr1+charArr2+charArr3
> - charArr1[]+charArr3[]+charArr2[]
> - charArr2[]+charArr1[]+charArr3[]
> - charArr2[]+charArr3[]+charArr1[]
> - and so on...

Please help me as I am confused in figuring out the algorithm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I thought I understood what you were trying to do until your fifth example, s+e+i+h (Match Correctly).
I couldn't see how you could get s+e+i+h by doing what I thought you were doing, because the last available "h" is in charArray6 and no "i" appears until charArray7.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. This problem is difficult to explain. I have edited the above to make it easier for you to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> Permutate(string[] array, int i, int n)
{
   if (i == n)
      yield return array;
   else
      for (var j = i; j <= n; j++)
      {
         Swap(ref array[i], ref array[j]);

         foreach (var s in Permutate(array, i + 1, n))
            yield return s;

         Swap(ref array[i], ref array[j]);
      }
}

public static void Swap(ref string a, ref string b) => (a, b) = (b, a);

public static bool IncMask(string[][] source, int[] mask)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < mask.Length; i++)
   {
      mask[i]++;
      if (mask[i] > source[i].Length)
         mask[i] = 0;
      else
         return false;
   }

   return true;
}

public static IEnumerable<string> Iterate(params string[][] source)
{
   var masks = new int[source.Length];

   while (true)
   {

      if (IncMask(source, masks))
         break;

      var array = masks
         .Select((i, j) => (i, j))
         .Where(x => x.i != 0)
         .Select(x => source[x.j][x.i - 1])
         .ToArray();

      foreach (var result in Permutate(array, 0, array.Length - 1))
         yield return string.Concat(result);

   }
}
```

Usage

```
var listWords = "la,lam,lan,son,som,some,mos,mao,sehi,noesrh,nroeh,doise".Split(',');

var charArr1 = "a,j,s".Split(',');
var charArr2 = "c,l,o".Split(',');
var charArr3 = "d,m,n".Split(',');
var charArr4 = "n,e,w".Split(',');
var charArr5 = "f,o,x".Split(',');
var charArr6 = "h,q,z".Split(',');
var charArr7 = "i,r".Split(',');

var results = Iterate(charArr1, charArr2, charArr3, charArr4, charArr5, charArr6, charArr7)
   .Where(x => listWords.Contains(x));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

**Results**

```
la, lam, mao, som, mos, lan, son, lan, son, some, mao, som, mos, son, son, some, doise, doise, sehi, nroeh, noesrh, nroeh, noesrh
```

Note, this is a fairly computationally heavy problem, I didn't put much effort into making this efficient, nor cared about duplicates. It could likely be solved many other (more performant) ways.
Also, I have only minimally tested this, so I am not responsible for anyone you maim or otherwise injure with this code. It could be completely wrong `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: wow, you are so impressive. I am amazed at your skill. In a short time that you can think of a solution to support yourself. Sincere thanks.

Comment: Please help me check again. When using your code, it throws an error here: ".Where (x => x.i! = 0)"

error code: CS1061 '(int, int)' does not contain a definition for 'i' and no extension method 'i' accepts first argument of type '(int, int)' (are you missing a reference use display or assembly?) test c:\users\admin\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\test\test\Form1.cs 80

Comment: @nanocovax there shouldn't be an error there, Its likely what framework you are using, it sounds like its having trouble with the tuples, are you using .net 5?

Comment: I use .net 4.7. :( can you suggest me which version to use? Thank you so much

Comment: @nanocovax  If you use, .net 5.0, this will all work. .net framework is a little old, if you cant use .net 5.0, let me know and ill give you compatible code